# Resizing UITabBarController Child Views

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm sure this is a matter of me not knowing how to phrase my question, but I'm at a loss.

I'm working on an app with 2 subviews that will be on the top of the screen at all times (taking up a total of 114 pixels including the status bar). I want the rest of the space to be taken up with a UITabBar and it's child views.

The closest I've been able to get is a tab view that is sized correctly but is positioned at 0,0 so it's under my persistent subviews.

```
// Create the main toolbar
toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
[toolbar sizeToFit];
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 20, 768, 44);

UILabel *textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(240, 20, 300, 40);
textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
textLabel.text = @"Character Name";
[self.window addSubview:textLabel];
[textLabel release];

...

// Create the stats bar
StatsViewController *statsView = [[StatsViewController alloc] init];
statsView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 64, 768, 50);
[self.window addSubview:statsView.view];

// Create Tab Bar Controller and Tab View Controllers
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

...

[self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
[tabBarController release];

[self.window addSubview:toolbar];
[self.window bringSubviewToFront:statsView.view];
[self.window bringSubviewToFront:textLabel];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

A tab bar controller (or any view controller, for that matter) will always try to resize its view so that it takes up the entire bounds of its superview. So if you want the tab bar controller to not do that, I would create another plain view controller that becomes your new root view controller.

In that view controller's view, you create 2 container subviews, one for your `statsView` and one for the tab bar controller. Now you add the tab bar controller's view to the one container view and the `StatsViewController`'s view to the other.

(Note: I did not test this.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, why create a subview that contain statsView, why not just one viewController with a container view (just a UIView instance, right?) sized to hold the tabBarController?

Comment: I created a new `UIVIewController` sized correctly and programmatically created the `UITabBarController` in `viewDidLoad` of the new viewController. I can see the tab bar, however none of the child views load and selecting a tab crashes the program. I feel like I'm very close.